# Mininig on CentOS 5

Tags: mining

I have been looking for an updated miner for my Centos 5 Server, however, I only found a very old miner. Is there miner or any techniques to run a miner on Centos 5?

Answer (score 1):

Try [xmr-stak](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak).

This should work for any linux distro.

```
wget https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/archive/v2.1.0.tar.gz
tar xzf v2.1.0.tar.gz
cd xmr-stak-2.1.0
cmake -DCMAKE_LINK_STATIC=ON -DXMR-STAK_COMPILE=generic -DCUDA_ENABLE=OFF -DOpenCL_ENABLE=OFF .
cd bin
chmod +x xmr-stak
./xmr-stak
```

The above compiles without Nvidia and AMD support. Otherwise remove`-DCUDA_ENABLE=OFF -DOpenCL_ENABLE=OFF`

If cmake command fails, install these first.

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl epel-release
sudo yum install cmake3 devtoolset-4-gcc* hwloc-devel libmicrohttpd-devel openssl-devel make
sudo scl enable devtoolset-4 bash
```

ref: [Issue #524](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/issues/524)

Answer (score 0):

Hyc's cpuminer-multi will work on CentOS. See https://github.com/hyc/cpuminer-multi

Be sure to install the following CentOS packages: `curl-devel libcurl glib-devel libtool`

Comment: thank you, sorry I made mistake, I am looking for Centos 5 in fact ??

Comment: @Berliner are you getting any kind of error when you try it in Centos 5?